# 'ColumnIndex' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using vb.net on a website (.aspx page)

The error I am having is:  'ColumnIndex' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'.

The code I am using is:

```
Private Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim CurrentCellName As String = GridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
        Dim CurrentCellValue As String = GridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim CurrentRow As DataGridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        Label23.text = "CCN: " & CurrentCellName & " CCV: " & CurrentCellValue & " CR: " & CurrentRow

        Session("PropertyID") = sender.SelectedValue.ToString
        PanelPropertyDetails.visible = "True"

    End Sub
```

Comment: try rowheaderclick event

Comment: Please see above amendments, still sadly get an error

Comment: When you say `Row value` do you mean the whole Row or do you mean the value of the `Cell` only?

Comment: I get the row value or did pre-edit. The issue I seem to have is two fold. 1 - what to put after "Handles" and then how to get the column name and value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the Current Column Name on Cell being clicked you could use:

```
Dim CurrentCellName as String = GridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
```

If you want to get the value of the Cell, you could use

```
Dim CurrentCellValue as String = GridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString()
```

If you want to get the whole Row, being selected you could use

```
Dim CurrentRow as DataGridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
```

To put it in your event handler of choice, it could probably look like this:

```
Private Sub GridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CellClick

 Dim CurrentCellName as String = GridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
 Dim CurrentCellValue as String = GridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString()
 Dim CurrentRow as DataGridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

End Sub
```

Comment: I still get error: Event 'rowheaderclick' cannot be found. Worth noting this is a DataGrid with VB.net? Nothing to do with WCF (encase that helps, I saw alot of examples with that mentioned that's why I mention it now)

Comment: Oh yes, I just copied and pasted your code and so I changed it now to `Handles GridView1.CellClick`. And yes this is not WCF but winforms. And I am using DataGridView and VB.Net as well. I tried it in my own PC and i was able to get the column name and as well as the value without problem.

Comment: Missed cellclick. I now get "'CellClick' cannot be found." I am using a Gridview not a datagridview though (assuming different). This Gridview is sat on an .aspx page online

Comment: But are you using asp.net or is this winforms (i.e. not for the web)?

Comment: Amended code at top of the page with error I am at. I have changed cellclick to selectedindexchanged